# htaccess removing extensions

Tags: .htaccess

Hi guys I am using this and I know the htaccess is working because it is redirecting to notfound.php but for some reason I can't get it to work to not show extensions (php/html) any help here?

```
<Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
deny from all
</Files>
Options Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 notfound.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.socialscenes\.co\.uk)(:80)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://socialscenes.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
DirectoryIndex index.php       
order deny,allow
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you will need much more than what you have to support hiding `.php` and `.html` extensions. Consider this code:

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php or .html extension
# To externally redirect foo.php ot foo.html to foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.(php|html) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```