# Remove From .PHP from the URL?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

When the user goes to `http://local/home`, it works fine, but if user goes to `http://local/home.php`, the `.php` stays there, it doesn't redirect to the page without the `.php`, so don't mark this as duplicate as I have researched it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any rule that redirects a request to a php extension to redirect without it. That's why it stays there. Just because you've added a rule to *internally rewrite* a request that is missing the php extension doesn't mean it magically happens in the other direction. At the top of your rules you need to match against the actual request and redirect the browser when it requests a php file:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /(.+)\.php(\?|\ )
RewriteRule ^ /%2 [L,R=301]
```

More:

- [htaccess remove php extension and redirect index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549482/htaccess-remove-php-extension-and-redirect-index)
- [htaccess removing extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318726/htaccess-removing-extensions)
- [Redirect .php urls to urls without extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222850/redirect-php-urls-to-urls-without-extension)

Just a matter of recognizing that a rule only does the one thing that its asked to do, match a pattern against the URI, and rewrite/redirect to the target.